# Verify my proof: If $X$ is infinite, then there exists $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $f$ is injective.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

**Proposition**: If $ X $ is infinite, then there exists $ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X $ such that $f$ is injective.

**Proof**: Define $X$ as a infinite set, i. e., there does not exist $ g: [k] \rightarrow X $ bijective for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Assume by hypothesis there does not exist a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X $ injective. So there does not exist a function $f$ such that for all $y_1, y_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$, if $y_{1} \neq y_{2} $, then $ f(y_{1}) \neq f(y_{2}) $.

Suppose a function $f$ that has the largest value of k such that, for $k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ elements of } \mathbb{N}$, if $y_{1} \neq y_{2} \neq y_{3} ... \neq y_{k} $ then $f(y_{1})\neq f(y_{2}) \neq f(y_{3}) ... \neq f(y_{k}) $. For other elements $y_{k+1}$ and $y_{k}$, we can have $y_{k+1} \neq y_{k}$ and $f(y_{k+1}) = f(y_{k})$. Hence we can have a function $ g: [k] \rightarrow X $ bijective and X is finite. **Contradiction!**

Q.E.D.

Comment: What is your definition of infinite set?

Comment: @caya, X is infinite when there does not exist $g:{1,2,3, ..., k} \rightarrow X $ bijective for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you check http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_set, what you want to prove is mentioned there and requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: But does it depend on axiom of choice?

Comment: Your definition is different.

Comment: Yes, this proof depends on the axiom of choice and it is possible that the axiom of choice fails and there are infinite sets which do not have such injections.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence in you proof has a wrong preamble. It should read:

> There does not exist a function $f$ such that for $y_1, y_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$, if $y_{1} \neq y_{2} $, then $ f(y_{1}) \neq f(y_{2}) $.

The last sentence is not clear at all. How is $k$ defined? I doubt you can turn that into a real proof.

To achieve the result you can proceed by induction to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists $f_n \colon [n] \to X$ which is injective and such that if $n<m$ then $f_n(k) = f_m(k)$ for all $k\in[n]$. You can then define the "union" of these function.

Comment: diagonalize! yay, i love diagonalization arguments

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini , I've re-elaborated my proof, check it again.

Comment: @Guilherm: I cannot understand your proof. Seems you are saying: take the function $f$ such that the maximal set where $f$ is injective, is maximal. It's not clear at all how you can define such things. Take $f(n)=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and explain what is $k$ for such a function. Also the notation $a \neq b \neq c$ is bad, don't use it.